# AWS ECR Total Images Storage view

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecr, azure-container-registry

I have recently started working with AWS ECR, I have uploaded approx. 1000 images having same base image but with some different custom layers for each image. Now I am trying to check about how much storage it takes on ECR for all the images to be saved, but I am unable to find any option as such to check the total size (though I can see the size of individual image).
So I have below questions :

1. As all these 1000 images have same base image, so what I think is that ECR will save a single copy of base image layers. Is this correct ?
2. I have worked with Azure container registry in past, there I can see the total size combined from all the images (see below image), Is there any similar option or command through which I can get the overall storage size currently being used by ECR (screenshot showing each image size is below for ECR) ?

**Note** - I have uploaded the same 1000 images in both container registries for comparison.

**Azure container registry screenshot :** You can see the total storage size used.

[image]

**AWS container registry screenshot :** You can see size per image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and created a bash script for this. It uses the `aws` CLI to query the repository data and image sizes and print the result as a table.

Example:

```
$ ./awc_ecr_stats.sh
REPOSITORY  SIZE
"repo-1"    402,95MB
"repo-2"    1,63GB
"repo-3"    1,70GB
"repo-4"    2,55GB
"repo-5"    2,76GB
"repo-6"    4,32GB
"repo-7"    9,08GB
"repo-8"    10,59GB
"repo-9"    13,68GB
"repo-10"   17,39GB
"repo-11"   24,48GB
"repo-12"   30,32GB
----------  --------
TOTAL       118,84GB
```

You can find the gist [here](https://gist.github.com/RafaelWO/8917d6b8618fa825304b706ea65ccbee).

Answer (score 0):

calculate the total size of all images in an Amazon(ECR) repository and display the result in gigabytes (GB), modify the script as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
repository_name="repo-name"
total_size=0
image_details=$(aws ecr describe-images --repository-name $repository_name)
for row in $(echo "${image_details}" | jq -c '.imageDetails[]'); do
    size_bytes=$(echo "${row}" | jq -r '.imageSizeInBytes')
    total_size_bytes=$((total_size_bytes + size_bytes))
done
total_size_gb=$(echo "scale=2; $total_size_bytes / (1024 * 1024 * 1024)" | bc)
echo "Total size of all images in $repository_name: ${total_size_gb} GB"
```

1. Create a ecr-calculate.sh file
2. Change file permission (chmod 777 ecr-calculate.sh)
3. Run sh ecr-calculate.sh